# How to get ICommandService object when workbench is not available

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am trying to get the commandService object using following code.

```
 IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
 return (ICommandService) window.getService(ICommandService.class);
```

But in one of the scenario, we will not have the workbench.

How to get the CommandService object when workbench is not available.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: But how can you get the window if there is no window running?

Comment: Please update your question with your scenario.  What are you trying to do that the Workbench is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the workbench is not available? Or is it just that **getActiveWorkbenchWindow()** returns null (which it will for example when called from non-UI threads). If this is the case, you can get the command service without an active window like this:

```
ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService.class);
```